# Ways of developing for small system. What is expedient?

Tags: design, architecture, maintainability

I'm developing a small system for internal automation. I use asp.net webforms and faced with a choice:

1. develop a system architecture in an object-oriented style (development becomes more difficult and time-consuming)

   or
2. just put controls on forms and write sql queries in control handlers (high speed development, the complexity of testing)

Сurrently I'm using the first method, but starting to have doubts that my choice is correct.
What way is expedient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Flexibility vs. formalism

There is a continuum between projects which require no quality (e.g. prototypes) and the ones which need the highest quality possible (e.g. life-critical systems).

[image: The diagram representing the described continuum]

On the left side, prototypes have one and one only goal: being developed quickly in order to show something, then thrown away. Here, writing quality code or following standards is not the point. The code is written once, and never read. High ratio of bugs is acceptable.

On the right side, life-critical systems require extreme caution when it comes to the reliability, which means that some particularly expensive techniques, such as formal proof, should be used. Here, a bug can cause a plane crash or a nuclear plant meltdown, which makes is extremely important to be as close to perfection as possible.

When moving from a prototype to a life-critical system, more and more techniques become required in order to either decrease the medium/long-term expenses or ensure some sort of compliance required by an authority. Those techniques come at a cost: they increase the immediate-term cost of the product. Those techniques include but are not limited to:

- Software testing,
- Informal and formal code reviews,
- Coding conventions,
- Compliance with the standards,
- Formal documentation,
- Static code analysis,
- etc.

### Locating a project

Where is your project on this continuum? If it's a short term throw-away project, just put controls on forms, ship early, and forget about it. If it's a project which have a potential of being maintained by several developers over years, then make it clean: your successors (or yourself a few months later) will thank you.

There are many factors which may help determining the position of the project:

- Are there many developers working on a project, or one only?
- Is compliance to precise norms required (think software related to accounting, for example)?
- Is the project made to be maintained for years, or quickly replaced by another system? Note that there is a bias towards small duration: some projects were thought to live at most two-three years, and twenty or thirty years later, they are still active.
- Is reliability required? A web app for your personal use may crash frequently; nobody will care. A business system which handles every transaction of every customer will cause much more trouble if it crashes from time to time.
- How many persons will use the product?
- etc.

If you don't know where to put your product on the continuum, ask your customer. Make sure it's written in a contract (I had customers who asked to deliver ASAP a prototype, then were truly surprised that it won't be maintained without rewrite, despite being informed by e-mail from the beginning). If nobody knows, apply YAGNI: do it as it were a prototype, but be ready to have to start from scratch if the project appears to be a good candidate to be maintained over years.

### Paradigms and processes

If you constantly fail shipping a product early, you may want to think about changing:

- Either the paradigms you use. For example move from static programming languages to dynamic ones, which often offer better flexibility and development velocity for web apps, without compromising code quality.
- Or the processes. For example, Agile enables to ship working products early, then continuously improve them, meaning that you have both high speed development and quality code together.

### To answer the question…

To finally answer the question:

1. You talk about a “small system for internal automation”. Seems like you don't need extreme quality. But still, be careful; you don't want to ship something bad, then maintain that for years. If it's really small, what about spending a few days creating a prototype, and then if it is successful, create the real app?
2. ASP.NET? Why not a dynamic language, such as Python? With Django, it is an excellent candidate for a web application which should be done quickly, and will probably be much cleaner compared to ASP.NET with SQL queries in forms.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. C# and ASP.NET are corporate standards, so we can't use other languages and frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Ehy if you start coding putting things here and there then your project becomes a mess!
Follow method number 1, as you are doing now, it will pay later.

Consider that an automation system, for how small it can be, must guarantee a reliable and affordable service for a medium to long period of time.

If you don't use a good structure and then you have to do maintenance in 2-3 years you will be thankful to yourself if you structure the design/implementation in a much better, organized and consistent way.

Even updating the system will be easier, if you continue with approach 1 and you have also the big advantage that you can recycle some code for other projects if the components are well designed.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't truly answerable without us knowing virtually everything about your organization, but here's a few pointers anyway.

Do not blindly listen to the advice that every line of code you write has to be perfectly abstracted and layered, ESPECIALLY for new systems. If you take your initial requirements, and create a perfectly layered, abstracted app, what will you do 6 weeks after deployment when the user come back and say "Oh, you know, what we ACTUALLY need isn't 'x', its 'y'." You will grumble and groan, and some programmers will actually try to convince the user that they are wrong about the new requirement. All because you've got a great architecture that you are invested in, and you don't want to rip it all out.

Sometimes the change that comes back after the deployment is minor, or maybe you understood the domain enough to anticipate it during your design phase, but that does not always occur. The change might be bolting on some NEW domain that you've got no experience with. In that case, its virtually impossible that your existing models can just be added to, you'll have to rip out, change, and transform LOTS of code.

My advice is always that for NEW software ("hey, can you give the sales guys a database for contacts?"), you should ALWAYS create a working prototype as quickly/easily as possible. Webforms with SQL datasources right there in the markup are PERFECTLY FINE for this prototype phase. Hell, are you sure you even need a real database? You can do a lot with NoSQL or just plain serialized objects on disk now, and its much faster to develop than coding to fill SQL tables. Use a UI framework like Twitter Bootstrap to cut down your UI time. Look into Entity Framework to speed up your data access, if you truly need to write to a relational database from day 1.

Just make sure you communicate that "done and deployed" means "I still need to come back in 2 months and optimize it". Bake those figures into your estimate, and when those post-deployment changes come back, just add in the extra time needed.

Depending on the level of change that comes back after the first deployment, you'll have to decide at what point you've become confident that you 'really' know the system is stable, and then take the time to break things out into proper layers. Premature optimization is the root of a lot of problems, and premature abstraction and layering falls into "optimization", in my opinion. Good luck with it!